# Spark: scala Any conversion

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to spark and scala. Therefore I faced some problem during type conversions. I have next peace of code that I ran in spark-shell

```
scala> val wa=queryResult.first.get(1)
wa: Any = WrappedArray(2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0)
```

So, my question is there some way to convert `wa` to `Array[Double]` type? Thanks!

Comment: `val wa=queryResult.first.get(1).toSeq.map(_.toDouble)` ?

Comment: @RobertUdah, `error: value toSeq is not a member of Any`

Comment: My bad. use `toList`

Comment: @RobertUdah, the same error is thrown.

Comment: What's the type of `queryResult`? A `DataFrame`?

Comment: @TzachZohar, yes, it's DataFrame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataFrame.first()` returns an instance of type `Row`, which supports a `getAs[T](i: Int)` method for this purpose exactly:

```
queryResult.first().getAs[Seq[Double]](1)
```

Internally, it performs exactly the same operation you did (`get(i).asInstanceOf[T]`), but it's recommended to use this shorter built-in method.

Answer (score 1):

So I've managed to perform desired transformation as

```
scala> queryResult.first.get(1).asInstanceOf[Seq[Double]]
res6: Seq[Double] = WrappedArray(2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0)
```